# Moderation on Tezos: We need candidates to step up for an election

Tags: discussion, election, moderators, moderation

**Update**: Given the level of interest expressed, an election kicked off on July 11th. Nominations are now open. See a full timeline on [this post](https://tezos.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/announcing-a-graduation-election-for-2022).

---

It is Stack Exchange's stance that every site needs to have a team of moderators in order to continue existing on the network. We have over 170 sites on SE; participation, the frequency of new questions asked, etc. varies from site to site. However, as long as a site has some activity and members willing to act as moderators, that's enough to keep a site going (see the "tangible guidelines for site closure" section on [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites)).

[If a moderator has been inactive for over 6 months, we typically remove their access to mod tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337431/what-is-the-process-regarding-moderator-inactivity-removals/338006#338006) and reach out to the rest of the moderation team to see if an election is needed to replace the outgoing moderator. Sometimes, if a site has a lower amount of flags or issues that require moderator intervention, the system will mark a moderator who is checking in and engaging on a regular basis as inactive, which is why the Community Managers always check in before automatically removing a moderator. However, we have found ourselves in an unusual situation with the Tezos Stack Exchange site.

Tezos Stack Exchange currently has two moderators, but both of them have been inactive for over six months. However, this doesn't appear to be simply due to low site activity (in which case the site simply wouldn't have needed much moderation activity). Rather, the current moderators do not appear to have been online in quite a while. There isn't a huge number of unanswered flags, but some of them have been there since late last year. We've reached out to the moderators several times, but we have not received any response back. We hope they are okay and that perhaps they are busy with other things, but we believe the time has come for this community to have some new moderators.

We'd like to get a sense of whether there are community members here who would be willing to step up and [run in an election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work/135361#135361). Your site recently left Beta, so this would typically be the time for us to run a "Graduation" election for your site, which would need to be competitive (meaning that the number of candidates must be greater than the number of moderator slots) in order to be successful. We could also run this as a Pro-Tem election, in which case a Community Manager can appoint qualified candidates if there are not enough candidates to make the election competitive.

We'd love to hear from your community regarding how much interest there is in keeping the Tezos Stack Exchange site going. New questions are asked on a regular basis, and there is active participation in the Q&A for this site, so it feels like there is value and engagement in this community. We just need 3-4 members willing to serve as moderators.

Any community member in good standing with more than 300 reputation (and who is at least 18 years old) may nominate themself to be a community moderator.If you want to know about what goes into being a moderator, see this Help Center page: [Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators)

We look forward to hearing from you, the Tezos Stack Exchange community. Once we gauge how much interest there is, we can work with y'all on scheduling an election and deciding whether it would be more appropriate to run it as a graduation election or a pro-tem election. **If you would be interested in nominating yourself in an election, please post an answer here to let us know.**

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough rep but this is the most important resource for me when it comes to tezos smart contract development

EDIT: I have enough rep now

Comment: nominating myself anyway because i'm here all the time

Comment: Thank you for your interest in moderating @0x10 but in order to run in an election you need to have 300 reputation on the site you wish to moderate.

Comment: my main SO account is in the top 6% with over 5k rep but i'm not willing to doxx myself, and people who answer questions don't usually upvote the questions no matter how well thought out they are so it's a stuggle to get rep on this stackexchange tbh

Comment: @Rosie I have enough rep now, may I please participate?

Comment: nominations have opened if you are still interested in running https://tezos.stackexchange.com/election?tab=nomination

Answer (score 2):

To make sure we have more moderators I will nominate myself. Rosie is it possible to reopen Ticket ID: 59278

Comment: I just responded to you. I'm glad you are interested in nominating your self in this election.

Comment: thank you for the response, we appreciate all your support

Comment: nominations opened today if you are still interested in running https://tezos.stackexchange.com/election?tab=nomination

Answer (score 2):

Thank you everyone for chiming in. It looks like we have a number of eligible site members who are willing to step up and nominate themselves. **We'll be kicking off an election with question collection beginning on Monday July 11th**.

Since there is enough interest and Tezos is no longer in Beta we are going to treat this like the site's first "full" election meaning it will be a competitive election for 3 slots so we'd need four eligible candidates to run. If we have less than four candidates that self nominate we'll treat it as a [pro-tem election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections) and appoint those candidates as pro-tem mods and try for a "full" election again in the future.

Comment: I have enough rep now please add me to the list of candidates

Comment: Congrats @0x10. The election will kickoff with an announcement and question collection on July 11th. The following week on July 18th at 20:00 UTC you'll be able to nominate yourself when nominations open up.

Answer (score 1):

Moderators are still able to post answers/questions like any normal user, they just gain extra privileges, correct?

I check this site usually at least once per day. I can't devote a huge amount of time, but I am able/willing to spend a few minutes everyday checking for issues.

I'll post a link to this in the community developer slack channel to see if we can get some more attention on this post too

Comment: That's correct Moderators can and are encouraged to still participate with Q&A. The additional role of moderators are outlined in the link I've shared in the post above. That post also links to the [moderator agreement](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement).

Comment: nominations opened today if you are interested in running https://tezos.stackexchange.com/election?tab=nomination

Answer (score 1):

Nominating myself as moderator.

Comment: nominations opened up today if you are still interested in running https://tezos.stackexchange.com/election?tab=nomination

Answer (score 1):

Nominating myself as a moderator. In 2018 I originally pushed to get this stack exchange going. I am also a moderator and admin across much of the Tezos ecosystem. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @RandixCapital but you need to have 300 reputation on the site you are interested in moderating in order to be eligible to run.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to nominate myself as well.

Comment: nominations opened to day if you are still interested in running https://tezos.stackexchange.com/election?tab=nomination

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved enough rep to participate, please add me to the list

Answer (score 0):

If you still need mods, I'll give a hand.

Comment: that's great. Nominations will open up the week of July 18th and you can nominate yourself at that time.

Comment: nominations opened up today if you are still interested in running https://tezos.stackexchange.com/election?tab=nomination