# Announcing a “Graduation” election for 2022

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Tezos Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [an election](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/election/3) on **July 18th**, as your “graduation” election [as a result of having lost your beta label a while back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374096/congratulations-to-the-59-sites-that-just-left-beta).

The timeline:

- On July 11th, I'll post a question collection post on Meta, so that the community can post questions they'd like to see the candidates answer.
- Starting on July 18th, users can [nominate themselves](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/election/3). The top questions collected on the previous week will be compiled into a questionnaire on the election page, so that potential moderators can answer them.
- Former moderators team will need to run in the election if they are interested in serving as moderators again.
- On July 25th, if there are 4 or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period there are still less than 4 candidates, I'll simply cancel the election and post to Meta to determine next steps. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-moderator-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-pa).)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on August 2nd (or August 9th, if we need to extend the nomination period).

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.