# What is the reason for the recent increase in volume of questions?

Tags: discussion

In 2022 [it was rare to see more than one question on this site per day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi9k1.png).

I was so glad to see that Tezos now averages about 2.4 questions/day:

[image]

Is it just because of this: [Moderation on Tezos: We need candidates to step up for an election](https://tezos.meta.stackexchange.com/q/62/1836), or has there been something else going on in the Tezos community recently, or is it for some other reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions are being asked in a dozen different forums/apps/channels. Numerous people (myself included) decided to push people towards asking + answering questions here instead

Questions are being asked in slack, discord, telegram etc. These questions and answers don't get indexed by search engines. Anyone searching for the same topic won't see any of these previous answers. We noticed dozens of the same questions being asked and answered in these private channels, so now we jump in and nudge people to ask/answer here instead, where its public and indexed

That combined with multiple new features/projects/partnerships bringing more people to Tezos, is also increasing traffic

Comment: This. We've also been reaching out to those various project-specific channels when a relevant question is asked here. This helps raise awareness of this site to the various development teams out there. With increased response rates and higher quality answers, it also encourages more questions, in a positive feedback loop.